# Feature Selection using MRMR

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I found two ways to implement MRMR for feature selection in python. The source of the paper that contains the method is:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4033100_Minimum_Redundancy_Feature_Selection_From_Microarray_Gene_Expression_Data

This is my code for the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
```

Method 1: Applying MRMR using pymrmr

Contains MID and MIQ

Which is published by the author
The link is  https://github.com/fbrundu/pymrmr

```
import pymrmr

pymrmr.mRMR(df, 'MIQ',6)
```

> ['Feature 4', 'Feature 5', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 6', 'Feature 1',
> 'Feature 3']

or running using the second way

```
pymrmr.mRMR(df, 'MID',6)
```

> ['Feature 4', 'Feature 6', 'Feature 5', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 1',
> 'Feature 3']

Both these methods, on the above dataset yields this 2 output. Another author on GitHub claims that you can use his version to apply the MRMR method. However when I use it for the same dataset I have a different result.

Method 2: Applying MRMR using MIFS

Github link

https://github.com/danielhomola/mifs

```
import mifs

for i in range(1,11):
    
    feat_selector = mifs.MutualInformationFeatureSelector('MRMR',k=i)
    feat_selector.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # call transform() on X to filter it down to selected features
    X_filtered = feat_selector.transform(X_train.values)

    #Create list of features
    feature_name = X_train.columns[feat_selector.ranking_]


    print(feature_name)
```

And if you run the above iteration for all different values of i, there will come no time where both methods actually yield the same feature selection output.

What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand as written. First off you say "I found two ways to implement MRMR" and then say "Method 1" but never say "Method 2". Are you trying to compare MIQ to MID? 

But more importantly, for the last example, you don't provide your output on your dataframe the way you do for the first part, so I don't think this is truly a 'minimum working example'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to contact either the authors of the original paper and/or the owner of the Github repo for a final answer, but most likely the differences here come from the fact that you are comparing 3 different algorithms (despite the name).

[Minimum redundancy Maximum relevance algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_redundancy_feature_selection) are actually a family of feature selection algorithms whose common objective is to select features that are *mutually far away from each other while still having "high" correlation to the classification variable*.

You can measure that objective using Mutual Information measures, but the specific method to follow(i.e. what to do with the scores computed? In what order? What other post-processing methods will be used? ...) is going to be different from one author to another - even in the paper they are actually giving you two different implementations, `MIQ` and `MID`.

So my suggestion would be to just choose the implementation you are more comfortable with (or even better, the one that produces better results in your pipeline after conducting a proper validation), and just report which specific source did you choose and why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes MRMR has two implementations MID and MIQ. In method 1, you can apply MRMR by specifying MID or MIQ explicitly. But in Method 2, what type of MRMR is the author applying there? MID or MIQ ? or a third different implementation ? Especially that method 2 does not have any similar output with Method 1, regardless of using MID or MIQ or iterating over the k values.

Comment: A third different implementation. Notice that in the source code of method 2, the author explains that for MRMR he actually used this other code: https://gist.github.com/GaelVaroquaux/ead9898bd3c973c40429 which is based in other papers.